# Compute the stationary distribution of a Markov Chain on an infinite state space

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a Markov Chain on $\mathbb N_0^2$ with a given initial state $(x_0,y_0)$. The allowed transitions for example are of the following form:

$(x,y) \mapsto (x-1,y+2)$ with probability $\propto x$

$(x,y) \mapsto (x+1,y-2)$ with probability $\propto \binom{y}{2}$

$(x,y) \mapsto (x-3,y+5)$ with probability $\propto \binom{x}{3}$

(So in the above example, $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ are absorbing states for $x-1, y-2, x-3$ etc. aren't allowed as we are on $\mathbb N_0^2$.)

I want to compute the stationary distribution of such a Markov Chain.

1. I need a judgement onto whether there is any hope for closed form solution for problems of the above kind. If yes, please refer me some material to read.
2. If not, I would want to find the answer using simulation. (My crude idea is that I would start at $(x_0,y_0)$ and watch several random walks. The histograms of the states observed would give me the stationary distribution. However I don't know how long should I be running the random walks. And if I need multiple random walks? So I need some suggestions on what should I be careful about. Also are there better ideas?)

Thanks!

Comment: Since there are absorbing states, the stationary distributions are trivial: precisely those distributions that assign total probability 1 to the absorbing states.  Is this really what you want to ask?

Comment: Maybe you mean _reflecting_ barriers to avoid negative values.

Comment: Yes, I think I want reflecting and not absorbing. Thanks for the suggestion. Although I am also curious about how the problem can be solved for the absorbing case - I still need to find the stationary distribution. And notice that even if I declare some states to be absorbing, from the initial point $(x_0,y_0)$ many may not be reachable.

Comment: A crucial remark is that the process 2X+Y is nonincreasing hence, for every starting point, the chain ends up in a small set of vertices S near (0,0). Thus every statiionary distribution is restricted to S.